# Where are the Ancient One's reinforcements?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, doctor-strange-2016

When Doctor Strange confronts the Ancient One, she deflects by pointing out that the zealots will soon return and they will need reinforcements. She leaves, presumably to gather said reinforcements. But when the zealots return, she intervenes by herself, with unfortunate consequences. What happened to the reinforcements she was supposed to have summoned? Why didn't she bring them along?

Comment: They were all off getting their heads polished and listening to Adele CDs

Comment: @Valorum I figured it would be Celtic Women because... you know...

Answer (score 5):

The implications are that she knew she would die either way. Remember that she leaves during the surgery to save her, and notes that she has never been able to avoid that moment (of death). I think she was afraid they would suffer her fate.

Answer (score 1):

More logically, you must remember that the Ancient One is drawing from the Dark Dimension, just like Kaecilius and his followers. Mordo points out that a connection with the Dark Dimension gives one more power in the mirror dimension, thus why Mordo and Strange are running from Kaecilius and his minions instead of fighting against such overwhelmingly powerful foes. The only reason the Ancient One is able to hold her own against them in that fight is because she also has a connection to the Dark Dimension. So even if she had brought reinforcements, they would have been as powerless as Strange and Mordo, and the fight would have been a slaughter.